# Can multicast send different information to different listeners?

Tags: multicast

How secure is multi-cast?  Is it possible to send different information to different listeners without them knowing it?

What if you got into the level of building your own custom hardware to do this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to allow nodes to stream information to other multiple nodes.  I would like to ensure that the same information gets to all the nodes and that someone can't attack the network by sending different information to different halves of the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP Multicast consists in broadcasting some content to multiple users at the same time, without having to deliver a each packet to every user. Which saves a lot of bandwidth.

The last device (ie. router) in the path, the one which delivers the packet to subscribed users in its area, is responsible for sending the packet to subscribed users only. Thus I would say there is no security in multicast.

Sending different content to every user is the opposite concept to multicast. It's called unicast.

Comment: Sorry didn't phrase the question well.. I understand that, what I would like to know is from a security standpoint, is it possible to send different content via multi-cast and disguise it so that subscribing nodes believe that they are all receiving the same thing.

Comment: I don't think so. For the same reason I wrote before: it's about the spirit of multicast. You can create multiple "channels" with different content. But one channel is going to be the same for every body.